# Pivoting Snowflake query with dynamic date values in either SQL/Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have searched many threads on this site about this but could not implement any of the solutions. I am using snowflake to pull data and then using the pivot function to transpose the table. Problem is I have to specify static fields in the pivot function. In my query I am pulling a date range of 90 days, so it would not be very efficient to constantly be changing the dates. I am pulling the data in Jupyter using the snowflake connection, so python is an option.

Sample query (this works):

```
select * from (
   select date, id, count(products) as prod_count 
   from table1 where date >= '2019-01-01' and date <= '2019-01-05' 
   group by 1, 2) d
pivot (
   max(prod_count) for date in ('2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-05')) piv
```

I have tried passing a select distinct date query inside the "for date in" piece, but that does not work. I have also tried creating separate dataframes and python lists containing all of the dates and passing those in instead but that does not work either. I have also tried various other solutions on this forum but they seem to be focused on TSQL or SQL Server syntax which does not work in my case (at least when I tried..) Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

To show a sample of input vs expected output:

Input:

```
Date        ID  Products
2019-01-01  1   A
2019-01-01  1   B
2019-01-01  2   A
2019-01-02  1   A
2019-01-02  1   B
2019-01-02  1   C
2019-01-02  2   A
2019-01-02  2   B
```

Current (and expected, but dynamic for the dates) output:

```
ID  2019-01-01   2019-01-02
1   2            3
2   1            2
```

Comment: can you show some samples of your data and where the dynamic part will need to be?

Comment: @Datanovice Edited my post to show you samples

Comment: Thanks, what needs to be dynamic exactly the SQL Query or the Python Code? from your output a simple pivot or groupby would always give the same result no matter the date?

Comment: @Datanovice in the SQL query you can see date >= 2019-01-01 and date <= 2019-01-05. If I change that to a larger date range at some other point in time, I would like the "for date in (....)" piece to not need static date input, rather just read a list of dates, which would then change the column headers in the output

Comment: got it, give me a while I'll provide an answer in Python.

Comment: I wrote a Snowflake stored procedure to get dynamics pivots inside Snowflake, check
https://hoffa.medium.com/dynamic-pivots-in-sql-with-snowflake-c763933987c   (also this question seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57172520/how-to-pivot-on-dynamic-values-in-snowflake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the range is 90 days you can tweak the function, but what we can do is return a dynamic query with your dynamic paramters as inputs:

```
import pandas as pd


def generate_sql_dates(start_date="2019-01-01", end_date="2019-01-05"):
"""Date Generator, takes in a start and end date"""
   date_arrays = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date,freq='D')

   pivot_dates = tuple([x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for x in date_arrays])

   return f"""select * from (
   select date, id, count(products) as prod_count 
   from table1 where date >= '{start_date}' and date <= '{end_date}'
   group by 1, 2) d
   pivot (
   max(prod_count) for date in {pivot_dates}) piv"""
```

running this returns :

```
qry = generate_sql_dates('2019-03-05','2019-04-05')
print(qry)
```

---

output:

```
select * from (
   select date, id, count(products) as prod_count 
   from table1 where date >= '2019-03-05' and date <= '2019-04-05'
   group by 1, 2) d
   pivot (
   max(prod_count) for date in ('2019-03-05', '2019-03-06', '2019-03-07', '2019-03-08', '2019-03-09', '2019-03-10', '2019-03-11', '2019-03-12', '2019-03-13', '2019-03-14', '2019-03-15', '2019-03-16', '2019-03-17', '2019-03-18', '2019-03-19', '2019-03-20', '2019-03-21', '2019-03-22', '2019-03-23', '2019-03-24', '2019-03-25', '2019-03-26', '2019-03-27', '2019-03-28', '2019-03-29', '2019-03-30', '2019-03-31', '2019-04-01', '2019-04-02', '2019-04-03', '2019-04-04', '2019-04-05')) piv
```

now if your date needs to be dynamic, i.e your running this daily and want it to start with a trigger, you can use a datetime function, much like `GETDATE()` in SQL:

```
start = (pd.to_datetime('today')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
end = (pd.to_datetime('today') + pd.DateOffset(days=90)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

you could then pass these into the function - or leave them as the default values.

Comment: sorry for the delay, I will try this in a bit. Will let you know if it solves my problem - thanks!!

Comment: @cexcelc glad this helped, let me know if you need any additional help

Comment: Hey, this solution worked, thanks! The only problem I am running into now is incorporating it with the %%snowflake function in Jupyter.. I can't figure out how to actually execute the query in Jupyter as i'm receiving syntax errors. For instance "%%snowflake Using... Using... qry" does not work. Neither does using select * from ({{qry}})"

Comment: @cexcelc that I have no idea about sorry! best to ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

I'll keep the most updated version of this answer on the similar question [How to pivot on dynamic values in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57172520/how-to-pivot-on-dynamic-values-in-snowflake).

I wrote a Snowflake stored procedure to get dynamics pivots inside Snowflake, 3 steps:

1. Query
2. Call stored procedure `call pivot_prev_results()`
3. Find the results `select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id(-2)))`

The procedure:

```sql
create or replace procedure pivot_prev_results()
returns string
language javascript
execute as caller as
$$
  var cols_query = `
      select '\\'' 
        || listagg(distinct pivot_column, '\\',\\'') within group (order by pivot_column)
        || '\\'' 
      from table(result_scan(last_query_id(-1)))
  `;
  var stmt1 = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cols_query});
  var results1 = stmt1.execute();
  results1.next();
  var col_list = results1.getColumnValue(1);
  
  pivot_query = `
         select * 
         from (select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id(-2)))) 
         pivot(max(pivot_value) for pivot_column in (${col_list}))
     `
  var stmt2 = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: pivot_query});
  stmt2.execute();
  return `select * from table(result_scan('${stmt2.getQueryId()}'));\n  select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id(-2)));`;
$$;
```

Check https://hoffa.medium.com/dynamic-pivots-in-sql-with-snowflake-c763933987c for more.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment, but I don't know enough Python to give you a fully functional answer. I can explain the approach for building a dynamic pivot, though.

Once you have your result set in place, use a tool to get a list of the distinct values from the column that you will be pivoting on and turning into column names. In this case, it seems like that will be your `date` column. As for tools, a SQL `SELECT DISTINCT` will work, but Python can do the same thing. One way or the other, take the list of values, separate them with a comma and wrap them in delimiters if need be (and for dates it will be needed), then save that comma-separated list to a string variable. That might be easier to accomplish in Python, but I think [it can be done in Snowflake](https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00006uSoErSAK/build-comma-separated-column-list-from-informationschemacolumns?), too. Whatever you're more comfortable with.

Next, you'll use that list of column names to build another variable that will have the rest of your query in it. In the `IN` clause, you'll append the variable from above with your column list.

```
SET @queryText = 'select * from (
   select date, id, count(products) as prod_count 
   from table1 where date >= '2019-01-01' and date <= '2019-01-05' 
   group by 1, 2) d
pivot (
   max(prod_count) for date in (' + @listOfColumnValues + ')) piv '
```

Finally, execute the query contained in `@queryText`.

Comment: Followed these instructions and received a syntax error on the SET @queryText piece.

Comment: And I'm not at all surprised. As noted, this is an approach, not a solution. You're going to need to fill in the gaps, or wait to see if someone offers up something more specific for you.