# Snowflake Stored Procedure Dynamic Column Pivot

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a stored procedure in Snowflake that pivot's the data in a derived table. The pivot columns are dynamic in nature. I have found a way to do this through parameter passing. I am trying to do the same without passing any parameters but the code is not working.

My approach has been to apply a loop at the table from which I am extracting the columns into a variable. Then pass this variable in the pivot. The while loop by itself seems to be working fine. The error comes when this variable is being passed to the pivot.

The code I am using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOOP_EXMPL_5()
returns  varchar
language javascript
as
$$ 
var column1 = 'qwerty';
var command = `SELECT ATTR_NAME FROM TBL_DIM`;
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: command});
var rs = stmt.execute();
while (rs.next()) 
   {
     var column1 = column1.concat(",","'",rs.getColumnValue(1),"'"); 
   }
var column2 = column1
var command_1 = `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW HIERARCHY_VIEW_2 AS SELECT * FROM (SELECT MSTR.PROD_CODE AS 
PROD_CODE,DIM.ATTR_NAME AS ATTR_NAME,MSTR.ATTR_VALUE AS ATTR_VALUE FROM TBL_DIM DIM INNER JOIN 
TBL_MSTR MSTR ON DIM.ATTR_KEY=MSTR.ATTR_KEY ) Q
              PIVOT (MAX (Q.ATTR_VALUE) FOR Q.ATTR_NAME IN ('${column2}'))
              AS P
              ORDER BY P.PROD_CODE;`;
 var stmt_1 = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: command_1});
 var rs_1 = stmt_1.execute();
 return 'success'
 $$;
```

The error I am getting:

Execution error in store procedure LOOP_EXMPL_5: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 73 unexpected 'Region'. At Statement.execute, line 16 position 21.

The variable value that is being passed:

qwerty,'Region','Sub-Region','Division','Company-Product','Company-Mfg','Company-Ship From to Customer','Business Unit','Category','Sub-Category','Segment','Sub-Segment','Brand','Aggregate Brand','Sub-Brand','PPG'

I will remove the qwerty part in the SQL somehow.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66109733/132438 and https://medium.com/snowflake/dynamic-pivots-in-sql-with-snowflake-c763933987c

Comment: See also [Snowpark Python approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76146342/5070879)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your objectives, see:

- https://medium.com/snowflake/dynamic-pivots-in-sql-with-snowflake-c763933987c
- [How to pivot on dynamic values in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57172520/how-to-pivot-on-dynamic-values-in-snowflake/66109733#66109733)

To debug the current problem: `column1.concat(",","'",rs.getColumnValue(1),"'");` is not escaping and quoting the column names correctly.

Set the UDF to return that value and then the value of `var command_1` so you can debug appropriately.

A good way to escape the columns:

```sql
select '\\'' 
        || listagg(distinct pivot_column, '\\',\\'') within group (order by pivot_column)
        || '\\''
```

And then use:

```sql
for pivot_column in (${col_list}))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Felipe. However, in the part where I am doing the column aggregations would like to why you have included the \\?

Comment: Also, when looking at the quotes used in the backslash, is there a reason there is a double quote post the backlash at the beginning, in the pivot listagg function, and the one in the end?

Comment: For further help, please paste the values printed by the function for `column2` and `command_1`. Then we can debug properly.

Comment: Was able to figure it out. Will post the solution here.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. Please upvote and or accept any answer that helped you, as a display of stack overflow gratitude

Comment: Done! That being said, I went a different route to the listagg function. Can you please explain why you added the backslashes? From my reading, it is a column escape character but did not quite understand how you have used it.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it! The backslashes are there so the final string will have `'` around the column names.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I will try to debug the listagg function as well since I keep getting syntax issues for that. (The backslash character) Sorry for so many follow-up questions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working code. Thanks a lot for your help Felipe and Greg.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOOP_EXMPL_9()
returns  varchar
language javascript
as
$$ 
  var column1 = "";
  var command = `SELECT ATTR_NAME FROM TBL_DIM`;
  var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: command});
  var rs = stmt.execute();
  while (rs.next()) 
   {
     if (column1 != "") column1 += ",";
     column1 += `'${rs.getColumnValue (1)}'`;
   }
  var column2 = column1;
  var command_1 = `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW HIERARCHY_VIEW_2 AS SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
  MSTR.PROD_CODE AS PROD_CODE,DIM.ATTR_NAME AS ATTR_NAME,MSTR.ATTR_VALUE AS ATTR_VALUE 
  FROM TBL_DIM DIM INNER JOIN TBL_MSTR MSTR ON DIM.ATTR_KEY=MSTR.ATTR_KEY ) Q
              PIVOT (MAX (Q.ATTR_VALUE) FOR Q.ATTR_NAME IN (${column2}))
              AS P
              ORDER BY P.PROD_CODE;`;
  var stmt_1 = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: command_1});
  var rs_1 = stmt_1.execute();
  return 'success'   
$$;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start with an empty string:

```
var column1 = "";
```

You can then concatenate the column list like this:

```
if (column1 != "") column1 += ",";
column1 += `"${rs.getColumnValue(1)}"`);
```

The reason you're getting the SQL syntax error is that the column names are in single quotes when they should be in double quotes.

Comment: Thank you Greg. I have tried with the double quotes. Getting the below error.                                  Execution error in store procedure LOOP_EXMPL_9: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 63 unexpected ''"Region","Sub-Region","Division","Company-Product","Company-Mfg","Company-Ship From to Customer","Business Unit","Category","Sub-Category","Segment","Sub-Segment","Brand","Aggregate Brand","Sub-Brand","PPG"''. At Statement.execute, line 17 position 21

Comment: PIVOT (MAX (Q.ATTR_VALUE) FOR Q.ATTR_NAME IN '${column2}')) --> I believe the single quotes added maybe causing an issue. I maybe wrong though.

Comment: You can go to the query history tab and see the SQL statement the SP is trying to run. Getting the whole statement makes it easier to fix. You can post it here if it's not too long and still need help.

Comment: Got it working! Your idea of looking at the history is what helped me debug. I will post the code I am using.