# Dynamic pivot or lateral flatten in Snowflake / Snowpark to columns

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Given this sample table in Snowflake:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE vnt
(src variant)
AS SELECT parse_json(column1) as src
FROM values
('{"a": 1,"b": 2,"c": 3}'),
('{"a": 1,"b": 2,"c": 3,"d": 4}');

select * from vnt;
```

I would like to output a table with two rows such as

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | NULL |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

meaning that I would like to flatten the JSON data into columns instead of rows.
I tried in Snowpark to flatten it, but I have the problem with the pivot as it does not work. And since the Keys can dynamically change, how could I handle this?

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    df = session.sql("select * from vnt")
    df = df.join_table_function("flatten", df["SRC"]) \
            .drop(["SEQ", "SRC", "PATH", "INDEX", "THIS"])
    df = df.pivot("VALUE",['a','b','c','d']).min("KEY")

    # Return value will appear in the Results tab.
    return df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be achieved by generating column list for pivoting:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import any_value

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    df = session.table("vnt")
    df = df.join_table_function("flatten", df["SRC"]).drop(["SEQ", "PATH", "INDEX", "THIS"])
    cols = [c[0] for c in df.group_by("key").agg(any_value("key")).collect()]
    df = df.pivot("key", cols).min("value")
    return df
```

Output:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

In order to remove `'` around pivoted columns you need to explicitly alias columns as per documentation:

> [PIVOT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot#examples)
>
> **If you prefer the column names without quotes,** or if you prefer that the output have different column names than the input, **you can include the column names in the AS clause, as shown below:**
>
> ```
> SELECT EMPID AS EMP_ID, "'JAN'" AS JANUARY, "'FEB'" AS FEBRUARY,
>     "'MAR'" AS MARCH, "'APR'" AS APRIL
> FROM monthly_sales
> PIVOT(sum(amount) FOR MONTH IN ('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR')) AS p
> ORDER BY EMPID;
> ```

Using Snowpark for Python:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import any_value, col

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    df = session.table("vnt")
    df = df.join_table_function("flatten", df["SRC"]).drop(["SEQ", "PATH", "INDEX", "THIS"])
    cols = [c[0] for c in df.group_by("key").agg(any_value("key")).collect()]
    cols_alias = [col("'" + c + "'").alias(c) for c in cols]
    df = df.pivot("key", cols).min("value").select(cols_alias)
    return df
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. Another thing, any idea at which stage I could replace the column names to remove the single qoutes? Something like `replace(key, '"')`

Comment: I did it like this, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way since I have literally 1000 columns

`for col in df.columns: new_col = col.replace('"\'', '').replace('\'"','') df =df.rename(col, new_col)`

Comment: @Dametime I have extended the answer with explicit aliasing.